# Groovy List of Lists or 2D Array

Tags: collections, groovy

I am new to groovy and I am writing a program for reading numbers from an input file which has the following format

```
1 
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

I wish to store them in a 2D array, how would I achieve it?

I have the following code so far for the read method

```
private read(fileName){
    def count = 0
    def fname = new File(fileName)

    if (!fname.exists())
        println "File Not Found"

    else{
        def input = []
        def inc = 0
        fname.eachLine {line->
            def arr = line.split(" ")
            def list = []
            for (i in 1..arr.length-1)  {
                list.add(arr[i].toInteger())
            }
            input.add(list)//not sure if this is correct
            inc++
        }
        input.each {
             print it
                //not sure how to reference the list 
        }

    }
}
```

I am able to print the lists but I am not sure how to use the list of lists in the program (for performing other operations on it). Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: You can change all of your `fname.eachLine` block to `fname.eachLine { line -> input << line.split( ' ' )*.toInteger() }`.  Don't understand the second half of your question, not sure what you mean by _"...I am not sure how to use the list of lists in the program..."_

Comment: For the second part, what I meant was how would I reference the list of lists for performing the array operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `input.each` all you need is to iterate again in each item in the row. If it were a collection of unknown depth, then you'd need to stick to a recursive method.

Made a small change and removed the `inc`, since it is not needed (at least in the snippet):

```
fname = """1 
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10"""

def input = []
fname.eachLine { line->
  def array = line.split(" ")
  def list = []
  for (item in array)  {
      list.add item.toInteger()
  }
  input.add list 
}

input.each { line ->
   print "items in line: "
   for (item in line) {
     print "$item "
   }
   println ""
}
```

Prints:

```
items in line: 1 
items in line: 2 3 
items in line: 4 5 6 
items in line: 7 8 9 10
```

That is plain simple iteration. You can use @Tim's suggestion to make it more idiomatic in Groovy :-)